# ¿Cómo hacer auto scroll hasta un elemento?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css3

Necesito que al momento de darle clic a un li haga scroll en el div con overflow hidden hasta el div que le corresponde.

```js
$("#menu li").click(function(e) {
     var div_load = $(this).data("id");
  $("#container").delay(100).animate({scrollTop: $("#"+div_load).position()().top }, 2000);
 });
```

```css
#container{
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid thin #c7c7c7;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
 <li data-id="uno">Paso 1</li>
    <li data-id="dos">Paso 2</li>
    <li data-id="tres">Paso 3</li>
</ul>
<div id="container">
 <div id="uno" data-id="uno">
        <h2>Primer DIV</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam efficitur ornare massa, ac tempor lorem vehicula eu. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ipsum eros, ultrices nec mollis sed, blandit ut metus. Quisque sed suscipit felis, non vehicula nunc. Vestibulum efficitur gravida tempus. In id sem et neque condimentum commodo ac sed metus. Fusce lobortis lacinia quam, sed tincidunt quam malesuada et. Sed eleifend lacus quis metus ornare, non lobortis dui placerat. Etiam in leo odio.

Aenean dignissim iaculis quam, quis lacinia lectus elementum et. Maecenas at neque fringilla, efficitur odio vitae, rhoncus turpis. Fusce volutpat, urna ac porta suscipit, eros ipsum tempus nibh, nec fringilla eros lectus in mauris. Cras non enim lectus. Pellentesque quis convallis odio, eu auctor odio. Proin tincidunt nisi nisi, sit amet laoreet diam feugiat sed. Sed vehicula ut eros eget tempor. Donec elementum quis dolor at molestie. Quisque a faucibus sem, ut venenatis nunc. Fusce imperdiet tristique sem eget vestibulum. Proin et leo in ex vulputate lacinia porta et odio.

Vivamus tellus metus, convallis non arcu vel, venenatis aliquet nisl. Aenean interdum elit libero, in lacinia nunc egestas vel. Vivamus sollicitudin sit amet lectus sed laoreet. Nullam euismod egestas nulla eget condimentum. Ut sollicitudin egestas sapien in malesuada. Donec eget interdum felis. Etiam accumsan tellus tortor, ac blandit arcu laoreet eu. Phasellus ultrices elementum nisi sit amet ornare. Proin scelerisque lacinia est nec sollicitudin. Etiam enim purus, accumsan quis mattis non, suscipit maximus dolor. Nam nulla ligula, lacinia vitae congue sed, sagittis porta neque. Pellentesque ante nisl, gravida quis eros quis, auctor pulvinar odio. In hendrerit eu felis eget dictum. Etiam dolor nibh, vehicula eget odio at, ultricies rhoncus lectus. Sed imperdiet, dolor eget maximus eleifend, arcu felis commodo dui, eu volutpat ex ex eu mauris.</p>
 </div>
    <div id="dos" data-id="uno">
        <h2>Segundo DIV</h2>
  <p>In eget lacinia diam. Aenean placerat blandit ipsum et maximus. Cras mi lacus, sodales et tincidunt eget, ullamcorper sed mauris. Duis eu vehicula metus, id lacinia lorem. Aenean fermentum quam nec interdum tincidunt. Nam in mauris porta, consectetur turpis eget, suscipit nunc. Aenean odio tellus, vehicula a nulla vel, porttitor porttitor lacus. Praesent varius tempus urna et luctus. Vivamus iaculis, magna et viverra euismod, lectus velit cursus diam, sit amet eleifend magna enim at sapien. Aliquam a scelerisque sapien. Praesent eu rhoncus risus, ut feugiat libero.

Maecenas at enim sit amet arcu porta feugiat. Mauris eget justo orci. Mauris varius libero nec vehicula volutpat. Maecenas rhoncus aliquam velit vitae egestas. Quisque nec volutpat velit. Mauris risus metus, hendrerit pulvinar diam ut, vehicula luctus neque. Fusce condimentum dui a fringilla vulputate. Vestibulum porttitor quam mi.

Nulla consequat consectetur tristique. Vivamus in iaculis felis. Pellentesque nec justo leo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas enim mi, placerat eget urna semper, laoreet scelerisque elit. Etiam rutrum eu enim ac egestas. Nunc fringilla, ligula vel semper ultricies, sapien massa iaculis ex, nec congue purus lorem non metus. Proin scelerisque nisl arcu, quis finibus ligula luctus id. Maecenas ullamcorper ipsum eu aliquet pellentesque. Cras rhoncus laoreet sollicitudin. Curabitur commodo rhoncus enim id lobortis. Suspendisse malesuada, eros id maximus molestie, lacus nibh condimentum leo, et facilisis erat ipsum sit amet mauris. Aenean placerat risus vel tincidunt blandit. Donec eu tempus lectus, vel sodales erat. Duis et elit enim. Sed sit amet venenatis urna.</p>
 </div>
    <div id="tres" data-id="uno">
        <h2>Tercer DIV</h2>
  <p>In eget lacinia diam. Aenean placerat blandit ipsum et maximus. Cras mi lacus, sodales et tincidunt eget, ullamcorper sed mauris. Duis eu vehicula metus, id lacinia lorem. Aenean fermentum quam nec interdum tincidunt. Nam in mauris porta, consectetur turpis eget, suscipit nunc. Aenean odio tellus, vehicula a nulla vel, porttitor porttitor lacus. Praesent varius tempus urna et luctus. Vivamus iaculis, magna et viverra euismod, lectus velit cursus diam, sit amet eleifend magna enim at sapien. Aliquam a scelerisque sapien. Praesent eu rhoncus risus, ut feugiat libero.

Maecenas at enim sit amet arcu porta feugiat. Mauris eget justo orci. Mauris varius libero nec vehicula volutpat. Maecenas rhoncus aliquam velit vitae egestas. Quisque nec volutpat velit. Mauris risus metus, hendrerit pulvinar diam ut, vehicula luctus neque. Fusce condimentum dui a fringilla vulputate. Vestibulum porttitor quam mi.

Nulla consequat consectetur tristique. Vivamus in iaculis felis. Pellentesque nec justo leo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas enim mi, placerat eget urna semper, laoreet scelerisque elit. Etiam rutrum eu enim ac egestas. Nunc fringilla, ligula vel semper ultricies, sapien massa iaculis ex, nec congue purus lorem non metus. Proin scelerisque nisl arcu, quis finibus ligula luctus id. Maecenas ullamcorper ipsum eu aliquet pellentesque. Cras rhoncus laoreet sollicitudin. Curabitur commodo rhoncus enim id lobortis. Suspendisse malesuada, eros id maximus molestie, lacus nibh condimentum leo, et facilisis erat ipsum sit amet mauris. Aenean placerat risus vel tincidunt blandit. Donec eu tempus lectus, vel sodales erat. Duis et elit enim. Sed sit amet venenatis urna.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con dos correcciones, el código que ya tienes funcionará sin problemas:

1. La función `position` sólo tiene que llevar un paréntesis y no dos (esto puedes ver que fallaba desde la consola de JavaScript). Entonces tendrías que arreglar esto:

   ```
   $("#"+div_load).position()().top
   ```

   y se quedaría así:

   ```
   $("#"+div_load).position().top
   ```
2. No basta con especificar que el scroll tiene que ser a la posición vertical del elemento:

   ```
   $("#"+div_load).position().top
   ```

   Hay que hacer unos pocos más cálculos porque `position().top` va a devolver la posición del scroll relativa al elemento que lo contiene, entonces no basta con poner la altura del elemento (que cambiará con cada scroll), pero puedes hacer esto:

   ```
   $("#container").scrollTop() + $("#"+div_load).position().top - $("#container").position().top
   ```

   Calculas el scroll que tienes que hacer con respecto a la posición del elemento contenedor (`$("#container").position().top`), el scroll que hay ahora mismo (`$("#container").scrollTop()`) y el scroll necesario para que vaya al elemento objetivo (`$("#"+div_load).position().top`)

Con esos cambios, el código queda así y ya hace bien la animación:

```js
$("#menu li").click(function(e) {
  var div_load = $(this).data("id");
  $("#container").delay(100).animate({
    scrollTop: $("#container").scrollTop() + $("#"+div_load).position().top - $("#container").position().top
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
#container{
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid thin #c7c7c7;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li data-id="uno">Paso 1</li>
  <li data-id="dos">Paso 2</li>
  <li data-id="tres">Paso 3</li>
</ul>
<div id="container">
  <div id="uno" data-id="uno">
    <h2>Primer DIV</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam efficitur ornare massa, ac tempor lorem vehicula eu. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ipsum eros, ultrices nec mollis sed, blandit ut metus. Quisque sed suscipit felis, non vehicula nunc. Vestibulum efficitur gravida tempus. In id sem et neque condimentum commodo ac sed metus. Fusce lobortis lacinia quam, sed tincidunt quam malesuada et. Sed eleifend lacus quis metus ornare, non lobortis dui placerat. Etiam in leo odio.

      Aenean dignissim iaculis quam, quis lacinia lectus elementum et. Maecenas at neque fringilla, efficitur odio vitae, rhoncus turpis. Fusce volutpat, urna ac porta suscipit, eros ipsum tempus nibh, nec fringilla eros lectus in mauris. Cras non enim lectus. Pellentesque quis convallis odio, eu auctor odio. Proin tincidunt nisi nisi, sit amet laoreet diam feugiat sed. Sed vehicula ut eros eget tempor. Donec elementum quis dolor at molestie. Quisque a faucibus sem, ut venenatis nunc. Fusce imperdiet tristique sem eget vestibulum. Proin et leo in ex vulputate lacinia porta et odio.

      Vivamus tellus metus, convallis non arcu vel, venenatis aliquet nisl. Aenean interdum elit libero, in lacinia nunc egestas vel. Vivamus sollicitudin sit amet lectus sed laoreet. Nullam euismod egestas nulla eget condimentum. Ut sollicitudin egestas sapien in malesuada. Donec eget interdum felis. Etiam accumsan tellus tortor, ac blandit arcu laoreet eu. Phasellus ultrices elementum nisi sit amet ornare. Proin scelerisque lacinia est nec sollicitudin. Etiam enim purus, accumsan quis mattis non, suscipit maximus dolor. Nam nulla ligula, lacinia vitae congue sed, sagittis porta neque. Pellentesque ante nisl, gravida quis eros quis, auctor pulvinar odio. In hendrerit eu felis eget dictum. Etiam dolor nibh, vehicula eget odio at, ultricies rhoncus lectus. Sed imperdiet, dolor eget maximus eleifend, arcu felis commodo dui, eu volutpat ex ex eu mauris.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="dos" data-id="uno">
    <h2>Segundo DIV</h2>
    <p>In eget lacinia diam. Aenean placerat blandit ipsum et maximus. Cras mi lacus, sodales et tincidunt eget, ullamcorper sed mauris. Duis eu vehicula metus, id lacinia lorem. Aenean fermentum quam nec interdum tincidunt. Nam in mauris porta, consectetur turpis eget, suscipit nunc. Aenean odio tellus, vehicula a nulla vel, porttitor porttitor lacus. Praesent varius tempus urna et luctus. Vivamus iaculis, magna et viverra euismod, lectus velit cursus diam, sit amet eleifend magna enim at sapien. Aliquam a scelerisque sapien. Praesent eu rhoncus risus, ut feugiat libero.

      Maecenas at enim sit amet arcu porta feugiat. Mauris eget justo orci. Mauris varius libero nec vehicula volutpat. Maecenas rhoncus aliquam velit vitae egestas. Quisque nec volutpat velit. Mauris risus metus, hendrerit pulvinar diam ut, vehicula luctus neque. Fusce condimentum dui a fringilla vulputate. Vestibulum porttitor quam mi.

      Nulla consequat consectetur tristique. Vivamus in iaculis felis. Pellentesque nec justo leo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas enim mi, placerat eget urna semper, laoreet scelerisque elit. Etiam rutrum eu enim ac egestas. Nunc fringilla, ligula vel semper ultricies, sapien massa iaculis ex, nec congue purus lorem non metus. Proin scelerisque nisl arcu, quis finibus ligula luctus id. Maecenas ullamcorper ipsum eu aliquet pellentesque. Cras rhoncus laoreet sollicitudin. Curabitur commodo rhoncus enim id lobortis. Suspendisse malesuada, eros id maximus molestie, lacus nibh condimentum leo, et facilisis erat ipsum sit amet mauris. Aenean placerat risus vel tincidunt blandit. Donec eu tempus lectus, vel sodales erat. Duis et elit enim. Sed sit amet venenatis urna.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tres" data-id="uno">
    <h2>Tercer DIV</h2>
    <p>In eget lacinia diam. Aenean placerat blandit ipsum et maximus. Cras mi lacus, sodales et tincidunt eget, ullamcorper sed mauris. Duis eu vehicula metus, id lacinia lorem. Aenean fermentum quam nec interdum tincidunt. Nam in mauris porta, consectetur turpis eget, suscipit nunc. Aenean odio tellus, vehicula a nulla vel, porttitor porttitor lacus. Praesent varius tempus urna et luctus. Vivamus iaculis, magna et viverra euismod, lectus velit cursus diam, sit amet eleifend magna enim at sapien. Aliquam a scelerisque sapien. Praesent eu rhoncus risus, ut feugiat libero.

      Maecenas at enim sit amet arcu porta feugiat. Mauris eget justo orci. Mauris varius libero nec vehicula volutpat. Maecenas rhoncus aliquam velit vitae egestas. Quisque nec volutpat velit. Mauris risus metus, hendrerit pulvinar diam ut, vehicula luctus neque. Fusce condimentum dui a fringilla vulputate. Vestibulum porttitor quam mi.

      Nulla consequat consectetur tristique. Vivamus in iaculis felis. Pellentesque nec justo leo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas enim mi, placerat eget urna semper, laoreet scelerisque elit. Etiam rutrum eu enim ac egestas. Nunc fringilla, ligula vel semper ultricies, sapien massa iaculis ex, nec congue purus lorem non metus. Proin scelerisque nisl arcu, quis finibus ligula luctus id. Maecenas ullamcorper ipsum eu aliquet pellentesque. Cras rhoncus laoreet sollicitudin. Curabitur commodo rhoncus enim id lobortis. Suspendisse malesuada, eros id maximus molestie, lacus nibh condimentum leo, et facilisis erat ipsum sit amet mauris. Aenean placerat risus vel tincidunt blandit. Donec eu tempus lectus, vel sodales erat. Duis et elit enim. Sed sit amet venenatis urna.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto poniendo en la dirección del link (href) el `id` o `name` del elemento 
    `<a href="#idDelElemento">Click aquí para ir al elemento ??    </a>`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_href_anchor

Comment: Una corrección: sería el `id` del elemento, y el `name` (que no el `class`) si el elemento es un _anchor_ (`a`).

Comment: Cierto, recordaba que era el `id`y supuse que también el `class`. Ya edité la respuesta. Gracias